# Distance between vector and a point

Tags: matlab, euclidean-distance

I have a point `point=[x y]` and a vector `vec=[X Y]`, where `X` and `Y` are vectors containing x,y values for many point. I have calculated the euclidean distances of all the points in `vec` from `point` with the following code:

```
    diff=vec-point;
    squared=diff.*diff;
    distances=sqrt(sum(squared,2));
```

I have seen the `pdist()` function, but could not find a good way to use it in my code. Is there a more elegant way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like `m = [point; vec]` and then `distances=pdist(m, 'euclidean')`, however it will compute `O((n+1)ˆ2)` distances rather than the `O(n)` you need. If the code is not performance critical I wouldn't worry about it and just use the code which is more elegant and easier to understand.